# Error: invalid contract address or ENS name

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat-deploy

My terminal is returning this error after deploying mocks when running `hh deploy` or `yarn hardhat deploy`:

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/01-deploy-raffle.js:
Error: invalid contract address or ENS name (argument="addressOrName", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

I was unable to find a solution online & my `01-deploy-raffle.js` seems identical to the one in the course.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this bug, plz?

`01-deploy-raffle.js`:

```js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { verify } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30");

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
    const transactionResponse = await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
    subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
    await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(
      subscriptionId,
      VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT
    );
  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["VRFCoordinatorV2"];
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscritpionId"];
  }

  const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"];
  const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"];
  const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"];
  const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"];

  const args = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    entranceFee,
    gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit,
    interval,
  ];
  const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  });

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("verifying...");
    await verify(raffle.address, args);
  }

  log(
    "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  );
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"];
```

Comment: Try console logging your contract's address after deploying it to ensure it was deployed correctly, you can add additional console logs throughout the code to find the exact line the error is coming from if the error message doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `VRFCoordinatorV2Mock` contract deployed before running the raffle deployment `01-deploy-raffle.js` that needs the VRFCoordinator address at

```
const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
```

There should be this script to run before you do the raffle one: `00-deploy-mocks.js` that deploys the VRFCoordinator contract with other mocks.

You can also add extra logging to see if the script is actually able to get VRFCoordinator address like this:

```
const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
console.log("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock address:", VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address);
```